# Ionic-4 wheel picker/selector buttons css customization

Tags: cordova, select, button, styles, ionic4

I am facing difficulty in styling the wheel picker buttons and splitter lines.
I want to change the default color of buttons and lines but I can't see any way of its customization.

Is there any way to customize its styling like we do in ionic-alert-controller.

Any response will be a great help. :P

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue too.
Basically, what you need to do is to pass class name(s) to the 'cssClass' property when you create the picker

```
const p = await this.pickerCtrl.create({
  columns : [
    ...
  ],
  buttons : [
    ...
  ],
  cssClass : 'pickerClassName'
});
```

In the Ionic docs you can find a list of css properties that you can enter to this class:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/picker#css-custom-properties

Now, the problem is that in that list there is no property for defining the color of the text, so I dived little bit into the elements structure and did it as follow:

In my "app.scss":

```
// Set the "secondary" color to the picker
.pickerClassName{

  // Border color (from the docs)
  --border-color: var(--ion-color-secondary);

  // Buttons color
  .picker-button {
    color : var(--ion-color-secondary);
  }

  // Options color
  .picker-opt {
    color : var(--ion-color-secondary);
  }

  // Selected option color
  .picker-opt-selected {
    color : var(--ion-color-secondary);
  }

  // Prefix color
  .picker-prefix {
    color : var(--ion-color-secondary);
  }

}
```

Comment: There is an option to define CSS class to each button and column, but I don't know what the css properties are for that

Answer (score 0):

You can individually customize the buttons with the cssClass property

```
let options: PickerOptions = {
      mode: 'ios',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'cancel-button'
        },
        {
          text: 'Okay',
          cssClass: 'okay-button',
          handler: (val: any) => {
            console.log(val)
          }
        }
      ],
      columns: [....]
      }],
      cssClass: 'picker-style'
    };
```

and in the global.scss file define the css classes like...

```
.cancel-button {
  color: red;
}

.okay-button {
  color: blue;
}
```